# Paypal IPN not updating database

Tags: php, paypal

I've read over many of the already submitted request for help and none have helped me. So I'm submitting my code to see if someone can help me.

So when I do a sandbox test IPN gets verified yet my code for when It gets verified isn't running. can someone attempt to help me?

The reason I do an update is because when someone click the buy button it enters a custom field into paypal with a record id for tracking, that's working but its not being updated.

IPNListener.php:

```
    <?php

    require_once("MAILER/smtpservice.php");

    function Connect()
    {
     $dbhost = "localhost";
     $dbuser = "root";
     $dbpass = "root";
     $dbname = "server";

     // Create connection
     $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die($conn->connect_error);

     return $conn;
    }

    $conn = Connect();

    class PayPal_IPN {

function ipn($ipn_data) {
    define('SSL_P_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    define('SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if (!preg_match('/paypal\.com$/', $hostname)) {
        $ipn_status = 'Validation post isn\'t from PayPal';
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            //You can send email as well        
        }
        return false;
    }
    // parse the paypal URL
    $paypal_url = ($_REQUEST['test_ipn'] == 1) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_P_URL;
    $url_parsed = parse_url($paypal_url);

    $post_string = '';
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
        $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
    }
    $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
    // get the correct paypal url to post request to
    $paypal_mode_status = $ipn_data; //get_option('im_sabdbox_mode');
    if ($paypal_mode_status == true)
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
    else
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);

    $ipn_response = '';

    if (!$fp) {
        // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
        // will be in the log.
        $ipn_status = "fsockopen error no. $err_num: $err_str";
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'fsockopen fail';
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        // Post the data back to paypal
        fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

        // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp); // close connection
    }
    // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the $ipn_status and log for details.
    if (!preg_match("/VERIFIED/s", $ipn_response)) {
        $ipn_status = 'IPN Validation Failed';

        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'Validation fail';
            print_r($_REQUEST);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        $ipn_status = "IPN VERIFIED";
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'SUCCESS';
        }

        return true;
    }
}

function ipn_response($request) {
    //mail("sanjeev00733@gmail.com","My subject",print_r($request,true));
    $ipn_data = true;
    if ($this->ipn($ipn_data)) {
        // if paypal sends a response code back let's handle it        
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            //mail send
            $sub = 'PayPal IPN Message';
            $msg = print_r($request, true);
            $to = "jcagnor@gmail.com";
            sendEmail($to, $sub, $msg);
        }
        // process the membership since paypal gave us a valid +
        $this->insert_data($request);
    }
}

function issetCheck($post, $key) {
    if (isset($post[$key])) {
        $return = $post[$key];
    } else {
        $return = '';
    }
    return $return;
}

function insert_data($request) {

    global $conn;


    $post = $request;
    $item_name = $this->issetCheck($post, 'item_name');
    $amount = $this->issetCheck($post, 'mc_gross');
    $currency = $this->issetCheck($post, 'mc_currency');
    $payer_email = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payer_email');
    $first_name = $this->issetCheck($post, 'first_name');
    $last_name = $this->issetCheck($post, 'last_name');
    $country = $this->issetCheck($post, 'residence_country');
    $txn_id = $this->issetCheck($post, 'txn_id');
    $txn_type = $this->issetCheck($post, 'txn_type');
    $payment_status = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payment_status');
    $payment_type = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payment_type');
    $payer_id = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payer_id');
    $record_id = $this->issetCheck($post, 'custom');
    $create_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $payment_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $conn->query("UPDATE donateinfo SET item_name = '$item_name', payment_amount = '$amount', payment_status = '$payment_status', payment_currency = '$currency', payer_email = '$payer_email', txn_id = '$txn_id' WHERE record_id = '$record_id'");
}

    }

    $obj = New PayPal_IPN();
    $obj->ipn_response($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: your UPDATE is missing commas as separators. Checking for errors on it would have shown you the syntax errors. Edit: this comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44665531/1 - I hope this isn't going to be an edit on the fly thing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still not working, I updated the original code to show what I've changed.